# Error ffmpeg and libvpx to convert to webm

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, libvpx

I have a problems with Ffmpeg and Libvpx on Centos6 Server.

**Command:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.mp4 -t 99 acodec copy -vcodec libvpx -f webm /var/www/f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.webm 2<&1
```

**Output:**

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (2997/50) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/vhosts/f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
  Duration: 00:04:16.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 650 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 108 kb/s
    Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 480x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 539 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Unknown encoder 'libvpx'
```

**Ffmpeg configuration:**

```
--prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
```

**Problem:**

```
Unknown encoder 'libvpx'
```

Comment: Have you already compiled/installed libvpx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ffmpeg` needs to be configured with the following:

- `--enable-libvpx` for VP8 and VP9 video encoding
- `--enable-libopus` for Opus audio encoding, **or**
- `--enable-libvorbis` for Vorbis audio encoding

#### Video

- To encode VP9 use `-c:v libvpx-vp9`.
- To encode VP8 use `-c:v libvpx`.

The default for WebM is libvpx-vp9.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) and [VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8) for more info.

#### Audio

You only need one of the above audio encoders: Opus is recommended over Vorbis, but either will work.

- To encode Opus use `-c:a libopus`.
- To encoder Vorbis use `-c:a libvorbis`.

The default for WebM is libopus.

#### Get `ffmpeg`

The easiest way to get `ffmpeg` with these encoders is to download it. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links for already compiled executables for Linux, macOS, and Windows. Alternatively, you can follow a [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

Comment: just for reference, -c:v libvpx will create VP8 and -c:v libvpx-vp9 will create VP9, but both should be available when you get --enable-libvpx